# Liferay Resources-Importer does not add articles to a page

Tags: search, liferay

I made my `sitemap.json` like this:

```
{
"layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
"layouts": [
    {
        "name": "Inicio",
        "title": "Início",
        "friendlyURL": "/inicio",
        "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
        "articles": [
            "genericBlock.xml", 
            "inicio.html",
            "formularioInicio.html"
        ]

    },
    {
        "name": "Pagina Menu Lateral",
        "title": "Página Menu Lateral",
        "friendlyURL": "/pagina-menu-lateral",
        "layouts":[
                {
                "name": "Link1",
                "title": "Link 1",
                "friendlyURL": "/link1",
                "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
                "columns": [
                    [
                    ]
                ]
                },
                {
                "name": "Link2",
                "title": "Link 2",
                "friendlyURL": "/link2",
                "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
                "columns": [
                    [
                    ]
                ]
                },
                {
                "name": "Link3",
                "title": "Link 3",
                "friendlyURL": "/link3",
                "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
                "columns": [
                    [
                    ]
                ]
                },
                {
                "name": "Link4",
                "title": "Link 4",
                "friendlyURL": "/link4",
                "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
                "columns": [
                        [
                            "link4MenuLateral.html"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Pagina Texto",
        "title": "Página de Texto",
        "friendlyURL": "/pagina-de-texto",
        "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
        "columns":[
            [
                "paginaTexto.html"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Noticias",
        "title": "Notícias",
        "friendlyURL": "/noticias",
        "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
        "columns":[
            [
                "noticias.html"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Search",
        "title": "Pesquisa",
        "friendlyURL": "/search",
        "layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
        "hidden": "true"
    }
]
}
```

When i deploy to liferay all runs nicely, but when i try to search for that content with Web Content Search, nothing is found. 
When i publish in web content all articles, then it founds the portlet url but never found the page where the web content is pointed.

**How can i make resources-importer publish automatically the web content?**

Further when i execute:

```
JournalArticleServiceUtil.getArticlesByLayoutUuid(groupId, LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayouts(groupId, false).get(i).getUuid()).size()
```

Returns 0 for all layouts.

**How can i make the sitemap include articles in layouts?**

When i add the content with drag & drop the search results fine.

Do someone faced or could give some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. I don't know how the content is structured (if both use the same xml file).

```
{
"layoutTemplateId": "1_column",
"publicPages": [
    {
        "columns": [
            [
                "formularioInicio.html",
                {
                    "portletId": "56",
                    "portletPreferences": {
                        "articleId": "genericBlock.xml",
                        "groupId": "${groupId}",
                        "portletSetupShowBorders": "true",
                        "portletSetupTitle_en_US":
                            "formulario inicio",
                        "portletSetupUseCustomTitle": "true"
                    }
                },

                "inicio.html"
                {
                    "portletId": "56",
                    "portletPreferences": {
                        "articleId": "genericBlock.xml",
                        "groupId": "${groupId}",
                        "portletSetupShowBorders": "true",
                        "portletSetupTitle_en_US":
                            "inicio",
                        "portletSetupUseCustomTitle": "true"
                    }
                }
            ]
        ],
        "name": "Inicio",
        "title": "Início",
        "friendlyURL": "/inicio"
    }
]}
```